# Macos C compilation error "ld: Undefined symbols: _main, referenced from: <initial-undefines>"

Tags: c, macos, clang, ld

I am having a compilation error on mac when I try to compile my c program error

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
     _main, referenced from:
     <initial-undefines>`
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried to reinstall xcode and command line tools, which did not work.

Comment: How do you build?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do 'clang main.c -o output'

Comment: And if you do `cat main.c` does it show you the correct contents of the file? Did you remember to save the file?

Comment: Did you save the file before compiling?